# Sending umdf driver created desktop frames to application

Tags: windows, driver, umdf

I have written a user mode driver that renders new desktop frames. Now I want to get those frames displayed in my application. I am already searching 2 weeks for any a solution but I still have no idea. By the way, I am new to windows driver development.
Does anybody have an idea how I could do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found this repo where someone implemented this: https://github.com/RileyWen/ScreenExpander

The way they did it was to send frames (as bytes) through a named pipe and then read that them from that pipe in a separate WPF app which displays the frames.

I tried to implement the same using sockets, which should be feasible, but couldn't make it work yet.